# What does k mean in AIC expression?

Tags: r, aic

I'm using the `AIC()` function in R, where the argument `k` (default to 2) stands for the number of parameters. I'm not sure to understand well what does it mean.

How can you know k?

For example, in the case of $y=ax^2+bx+c$, does k equal 3?

As a sidenote, I saw that there is a function named `sic()` which comes with the `metomet` package. However, I can't install this package as it doesn't seem to be available for latest release of R (version 2.13.0). Do you know where it can be found?

Comment: It seems that you asking 2 different questions, one about AIC, another about installing certain R package. Please ask 2 different questions.

Comment: Package metomet is not in the list of available, archived or orphaned packages. Rseek.org also gives nothing, so the question is why are you certain that such package exists at all?

Comment: Maybe this one? http://forums.cirad.fr/logiciel-R/viewtopic.php?t=2688&sid=bbd0e8ff814c3f00ec8458befa65c6db

Answer (score 5):

k in AIC is a multiplier for the penalty term for complexity. The usual AIC, as developed by Akaike, used k = 2, so that is the default. In the BIC or SBC, k = log(n), where n is the number of observations. Either of these (or other similar measures) follow a formula

-2 loglikelihood + k*p

where p is the number of parameters. The penalty term for complexity is to make up for the fact that more complex models fit better, even if the added terms aren't very useful.

Comment: So k doesn't have to be an integer?

Comment: Nope, apparently not.